# unable to set proper scope for variable within a JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, es6-promise

I've come across a weird issue where a new variable is being created in local scope even if it is defined outside,

from the below code

after I call buildMeta() and check the contents of "data", it is always empty 
implying that it's not being modified at all, even if I've specifically targeted "that.data" where that refers to the class' object.

I'd appreciate if anyone would point out what I am doing wrong.

```
class meta {

    constructor(files) {
        if(!files) throw Error("files not specified");
        this.data = {};
        this.ls = files;
    }

  buildMeta() {
        var that = this;
        for(let i = 0; i < that.ls.length; i++) {

            mm.parseFile(that.ls[i]).then(x => {
                var info = x.common;
                that.data[info.artist] = "test";
            }).catch((x) => { 
               console.log(x);    
            });
       }

    }
 }
const mm = new meta(indexer); // indexer is an array of file paths
mm.buildMeta();
console.log(mm.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging `mm.data` before `parseFile` has finished. Your code implies that it returns a promise, so your insertion into `that.data` will happen after your `console.log(mm.data)` executes.

You need to return a promise from `buildMeta`, so that you can do...

```
const mm = new meta(indexer);
mm.buildMeta().then(() => {
    console.log(mm.data);
})
```

Here's a `buildMeta` that should do what you need. This returns a promise that waits for all of the parseFile invocations to do their work and update `this.data`...

```
buildMeta() {
    return Promise.all(this.ls.map(f => mm.parseFile(f).then(x => {
        var info = x.common;
        this.data[info.artist] = "test";
    })))
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it's value is still {}, https://pastebin.com/tmH6tCLv
Promises are a little confusing for me.

Comment: I've added an implementation of buildMeta for you to try.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing sync with async code here.
The for loop won't wait for the `parseFile` promises to resolve.
You could use `Promise.all` to fill in the data when the files are parsed.

```
// Class names should be written using a capital letter 
class Meta {
    ...
    buildMeta() {
     // You don't need this assignment since you're using arrow functions
    // var that = this;
    const promises = this.ls.map(filePath => mm.parseFile(filePath));
    return Promise.all(promises).then(resolvedPromises => {
        resolvedPromises.map(({ parsedFile }) => {
            this.data[parsedFile.common.artist] = "test";
       });
       return this.data;
    }).catch(console.error);
}

...

const mm = new meta(indexer); // indexer is an array of file paths
mm.buildMeta().then(data => {console.log(data)});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll try and learn more concepts of Promises now.